# Assigning to objects using names created from a vector in R

Tags: r, assign

I have two vectors:

```
years<-c(1995:1999)
values<-c(1:5)
```

I want to create five objects, named "Obj1995", "Obj1996" etc., and assign them the values in `values` in that order, so that `Obj1995==1`, `Obj1996==2` etc.

I tried using `assign()`:

```
assign(paste0("Obj",years),values)
```

but that's not vectorized, so it only created one object, containing all of `values`:

```
In assign(paste0("Obj",years),values) :
  only the first element is used as variable name
```

Is there a way of achieving my goal without a for-loop?

Comment: Fyi, the usual advice is: don't do that. Both don't create a bunch of objects that naturally fit together in one object; and don't embed data (in this case years) in strings. That is, `yr_DF = data.frame(yr = years, v = values)` or similar...

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this advice, and have taken it into consideration. The actual use case isn't as simple as the example, and while I could put everything into a list, having multiple-dimension arrays as list objects just becomes too cumbersome to reference for my needs.

Comment: `library("fortunes");
fortune(236)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `list2env` on a `named` `list`

```
list2env(as.list(setNames(values, paste0("Obj", years))), envir = .GlobalEnv)

Obj1995
#[1] 1
Obj1996
#[1] 2
```

---

The `assign` can be used with a `for` loop

```
rm(list = ls(pattern = "^Obj\\d{4}$")) # remove any objects 
for(i in seq_along(values)) assign(paste0("Obj", yearsi]), value = values[i])
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I figured out the for-loop option myself, but wanted to figure out a vectorized alternative. Your answer flipped years and values, but I got the gist of it, and got it to work. I actually saw list2env in another answer, but it didn't have the satNames part, and I couldn't figure that bit out.